# Can anyone help me solve this problem? Flutter in Visual Studio Code

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

```
* What went wrong:
```

Execution failed for task ':generateDebugBuildConfig'.

> Error while evaluating property 'namespace' of task ':generateDebugBuildConfig'
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':generateDebugBuildConfig' property 'namespace'.
> > Failed to calculate the value of property 'namespace'.
> > Manifest file does not exist: C:\Users\xxxx\ar_flutter_app\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

im taking this error when i connected to my android device and try to run the apps in my device

```
here is my manifest file
```

```js
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   package="com.example.flutter_ar"
          android:versionCode="1000"
          android:versionName="1.0.0">
    <application
        android:label="ar_flutter_app"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

**try**

`flutter clean`

`flutter pub get`

`flutter run`

Comment: i tried it, but still showing the same error

Comment: why there is a version code and version name in manifest